# Reactive Form Validation not working with ControlValueAccessor

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-forms

I've created a simple nested form that depends on the child component rather than putting everything into one component.
I've implemented a very basic ControlValueAccessor to enable it to work in such fashion, however what I noticed is that validation doesn't get captured at parent component. This means a faulty form can be submitted even though its not valid.

How do i get the validation of child forms to propagate up to the parent form.

Below is the code.

Parent HTML

```
<form [formGroup]="parentForm" (ngSubmit)="submitData()">
    <h3>Parent</h3>
    <br>
    <ng-container formArrayName="children">
        <ng-container *ngFor="let c of children?.controls; index as j">
            <app-child [formControlName]="j"></app-child>
        </ng-container>
    </ng-container>

    <button mat-raised-button type="button" (click)="addChild()">Add Activity</button>
    <button mat-raised-button type="submit" color="warn" [disabled]="!parentForm.valid">Submit</button>
</form>

<pre>
{{parentForm.valid}} // this is always true because its not getting validator state from children
</pre>
<pre>
{{parentForm.value | json}}
</pre>
```

Parent TS

```
export class ParentComponent implements OnInit {
  parentForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.createForm();
  }

  private createForm() {
    this.parentForm = this.fb.group({
      children: this.fb.array([])
    });
  }

  get children(): FormArray {
    return this.parentForm.get("children") as FormArray;
  }

  addChild() {
    const tempChild = new FormControl({
      description: null
    });

    this.children.push(tempChild);
  }

  submitData() {
    console.info(JSON.stringify(this.parentForm.value));
  }
}
```

Child HTML

```
<form [formGroup]="newChildForm">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <mat-form-field>
                <mat-label>Description</mat-label>
                <input type="text" matInput formControlName="description" required>
            </mat-form-field>
        </td>
    </tr>
</form>
```

Child TS

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  templateUrl: './child.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./child.component.scss'],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
      useExisting: forwardRef(() => ChildComponent),
      multi: true
    }
  ]
})
export class ChildComponent implements ControlValueAccessor, OnInit {
  newChildForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.createForm();
  }

  private createForm() {
    this.newChildForm = this.fb.group({
      description: [null, Validators.required],
    });
  }

  onTouched: () => void = () => { };

  writeValue(value: any) {
    if (value) {
      this.newChildForm.setValue(value, { emitEvent: true });
    }
  }

  registerOnChange(fn: (v: any) => void) {
    this.newChildForm.valueChanges.subscribe((val) => {
      fn(val);
    });
  }

  setDisabledState(disabled: boolean) {
    disabled ? this.newChildForm.disable() : this.newChildForm.enable();
  }

  registerOnTouched(fn: () => void) {
    this.onTouched = fn;
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {  }
}
```

[Stackblitz Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-eh2fl6?file=src/parent/parent.component.ts)

EDIT 2: nested approach

[Stackblitz Link with Validator and ChangeDetection](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-fekrkw?file=src/parent/parent.component.ts)

Comment: Would you like to share your angular code with this https://stackblitz.com/ `angular editor`, ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can achieve that by implementing [Validator](https://angular.io/api/forms/Validator) interface in your child component, which requires to write your `validate` method within child component, to be checked every time the value changes, and it could be like the following in your case:

```js
@Component({
  selector: "app-child",
  templateUrl: "./child.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./child.component.css"],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
      useExisting: forwardRef(() => ChildComponent),
      multi: true,
    },
    {
      // >>>>>> 1- The NG_VALIDATORS should be provided here <<<<<
      provide: NG_VALIDATORS,
      useExisting: ChildComponent,
      multi: true,
    },
  ],
})
export class ChildComponent implements ControlValueAccessor, Validator, OnInit {
  newChildForm: FormGroup;

  onChange: any = () => {};
  onValidationChange: any = () => {};

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef) {
    this.createForm();
  }

  private createForm() {
    this.newChildForm = this.fb.group({
      description: [null, Validators.required],
      children: this.fb.array([]),
    });
  }

  onTouched: () => void = () => {};

  writeValue(value: any) {
    if (value) {
      this.newChildForm.setValue(value, { emitEvent: true });
    }
  }

  registerOnChange(fn: (v: any) => void) {
    this.onChange = fn;
  }

  setDisabledState(disabled: boolean) {
    disabled ? this.newChildForm.disable() : this.newChildForm.enable();
  }

  registerOnTouched(fn: () => void) {
    this.onTouched = fn;
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.newChildForm.valueChanges.subscribe((val) => {
      this.onChange(val);

      // >>>> 4- call registerOnValidatorChange after every changes to check validation of the form again <<<<
      this.onValidationChange();
    });
  }

  // >>>> 2- validate method should be added here <<<<
  validate(): ValidationErrors | null {
    if (this.newChildForm?.invalid) {
      return { invalid: true };
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }

  // >>>> 3- add registerOnValidatorChange to call it after every changes <<<<
  registerOnValidatorChange?(fn: () => void): void {
    this.onValidationChange = fn;
  }

  get children(): FormArray {
    return this.newChildForm.get("children") as FormArray;
  }

  addChild() {
    const tempChild = new FormControl({
      description: null,
      children: [],
    });

    this.children.push(tempChild);
    this.cdr.detectChanges();
  }
}
```

Comment: So where do i implement that? Can you demonstrate in the code i have posted?

Comment: I updated my answer with the required changes to your child-component.
Please take care of `>>>>> 1-2-3 <<<< ` changes.

Comment: I did that and it partially worked, this is the error that it throws now: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'false'. Current value: 'true'

Comment: Could you please create a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/) for your code, so we can help where is the problem exactly?

Comment: Done its been added

Comment: Inject `ChangeDetectorRef` into parent-compoennt's constructor `constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef) {}` then call `this.cdr.detectChanges();` after  `this.children.push(tempChild);` directly within parent-component, to tell Angular to detect changes after adding the child component.

Comment: That works for the immediate child, however the minute you expand to nested children it, validation breaks again. I created a second stackblitz with examples and your recommended changes. Btw I'll accept your answer if you think this is taking it too complicated

Comment: I updated my answer with your latest code. To resolve this issue you need to add [registerOnValidatorChange](https://angular.io/api/forms/Validator#registeronvalidatorchange) to register the validation change function, to be used on every change. Please take a look at `>>>> 3-4 <<<<` changes notes.

Comment: That works on stackblitz, not on local. I've accepted your answer and will now dig into my code. Thanks for the help